# Show that $\underset{N\to\infty}{\lim}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [g(t)\cos(\frac{t}{2})]\sin(Nt)dt=0$, where $g(t)=\frac{f(x-t)-f(x)}{\sin(t/2)}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**Problem**: $\underset{N\to\infty}{\lim}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [g(t)\cos(\frac{t}{2})]\sin(Nt)dt=0$, where $g(t)=\frac{f(x-t)-f(x)}{\sin(t/2)}$.

The Problem arises from Walter Rudin's PMA:
[image]

For the texts highlighted in blue: the boundedness of $g(t)\sin(t/2)$ is trivial; and to show the boundedness of $g(t)\cos(t/2)$, I suppose we show that $\underset{t\to 0}{\lim}\frac{t}{cos(t/2)}=2$, then combine it with (79) and (81). But the texts highlighted in yellow really trouble me. (74) states that "$\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}c_n=0$", where $c_n$ is the n^th Fourier coefficient of $f$ relative to an orthonormal series ${\phi_n(x)}$. Here I believe $c_n=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\overline{\phi_n(t)}dt$ by (66). But then how does that lead to "$\int_{-\pi}^\pi [g(t)\cos\frac{t}{2}]\sin Nt dt$ and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi [g(t)\sin\frac{t}{2}]\cos Nt dt$ tend to $0$ as $N\to\infty$"?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $|\int g(t) \cos(t/2) sin(Nt) dt| \le M \int |\sin(Nt)| dt \to 0 $ as $N \to \infty$. Same for the other integral

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. I have impression that $\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi |\sin(Nt)|\,dt=4$

Comment: The function $g(t)$ is bounded for $ |t|$ small by $(79).$ I guess that it is assumed that $f$ is absolutely integrable (or continuous) and so is $g.$ The conclusion then follows from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc That's not very characteristic of Rudin to use a theorem he never even mentioned...

Comment: @DickGrayson Actually $(74)$ is called the Riemann-Lebesque lemma. There $\phi_n=e^{int},$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ but $\sin nt={1\over 2i}[e^{int}-e^{-int}]$ and thus you can make use of $(74).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc"...and thus you can make use of (74)". First, I don't believe $\phi_n(x)=e^{int}$ is orthonormal, because $(2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{int}$ is (on $[-\pi, \pi])$. No big deal. The real issue is, (74) only implies $\underset{N\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{iNt}dt=0$, from which I have a hard time deducing $\underset{N\to\infty}{\lim}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [g(t)\cos\frac{t}{2}]\sin Nt dt=0$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Even if we make use of the identity $\sin nt={1\over 2i}[e^{int}-e^{-int}]$ that you provided, we can only get $\underset{N\to\infty}{\lim}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [g(t)\cos\frac{t}{2}]\sin Nt dt=\underset{N\to\infty}{\lim}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [g(t)\cos\frac{t}{2}][e^{iNt}-e^{-iNt}] dt$, which I don't know why is equal to $0$...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136204/discussion-between-dick-grayson-and-ryszard-szwarc).

Comment: @DickGrayson The basis is enumerated by integer numbers therefore the Bessel inequality implies $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |c_n|^2<\infty. $ Thus $c_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$ and $c_{-n}\to 0$ when $n\to \infty.$ Shortly $c_n\to 0$ when $|n|\to \infty$